# Change Background Color View with Fade In animation from boolean

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

I'm using a boolean to determine the backgroundColor of a View

```
const selectColor = isSelected ? "#8bc34a" : "#e9e9e9";

...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleSelection}>
 <View style={{ backgroundColor: selectColor }}>
 </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I'd like that this color switch changes with a FadeIn Animation using the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html)

Main issue is, my inputRange is a boolean.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possibly make your inputRange the two colors converted to an integer?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

[image]

You can animate the `opacity` property of the `style` object. You have a main `View` whose background color is `#e9e9e9` and a nested `Animated.View` whose background color is `#8bc34a` but opacity is 0 at first, when toggle, the opacity becomes 1, the code for the Gif above is:

```
class TestScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.opacity = new Animated.Value(0);

        this.toggleBackgroundColor = this.toggleBackgroundColor.bind(this);
    }

    toggleBackgroundColor() {
        Animated.timing(this.opacity, {
            toValue: this.opacity._value ? 0 : 1,
            duration: 1000
        }).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#8BC34A'
                }}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#4099FF', zIndex: 1 }}
                    onPress={this.toggleBackgroundColor}
                >
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: '#4099FF', margin: 16 }}>
                        Toggle
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Animated.View
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, top: 0,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9',
                        opacity: this.opacity
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default TestScreen;
```

Comment: Using as an Animated Value is a good trick. Therefore, how do you go from a Red to a Green for instance ?
Seems like you can't if you stick to the opacity property